# Angular 2 Dynamically disable FormControl

Tags: angular

I've a simple form group, with 2 form controls. Initially both the controls have required validation.

I also have a button in the template. When clicking the button, i want to change the behavior of the form group. ie., Both the controls need to be disabled & and the validation needs to be removed.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ganeshtechie-form-control-example)

```js
import {
  Component,
  AfterViewInit,
  ViewChild
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  Validators
} from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  name = 'Angular 6';

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

    let username = this.fb.control.apply(null, [{
      value: 'gannr',
      disabled: false
    }, Validators.required])

    let password = this.fb.control.apply(null, [{
      value: 'hello',
      disabled: false
    }, Validators.required]);

    this.form = this.fb.group({
      username: username,
      password: password
    });


  }


  changeFormBehavior() {

    let username = this.fb.control.apply(null, [{
      value: 'gannr disabled',
      disabled: true
    }]);

    let password = this.fb.control.apply(null, [{
      value: 'hello',
      disabled: true
    }]);

    this.form = this.fb.group({
      username: username,
      password: password
    });

  }



}
```

Comment: Could I know why you unmarked your answer as resolved ?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe if you used the correct variables and syntax ...

```
  changeFormBehavior() {
    this.form.get('username').disable();
    this.form.get('password').disable();
    this.form.get('username').setValidators(null);
    this.form.get('password').setValidators(null);
 }
```

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ganeshtechie-form-control-example-ttgvfk?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Why the form status is invalid even after removing the validation ?

Comment: nope. it didn't work. i also tried clearing the validation by calling clearValidators method

Comment: I see that, let me find out why for a second

Comment: It's not valid because it's empty (disabling a controls removes it from the value of the form). Remove `this.form.updateValueAndValidity()` and `this.form.get('password').disable()`, and it becomes valid. Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ganeshtechie-form-control-example-4itkzh?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Is there any workaround to have all the formcontrol's disabled and still get the form to be valid ?

Comment: Don't think so. You can compare the form to an empty object instead of checking if it's valid with `{{ form.valid || form.value === {} }}`

Comment: i tried that. form.value still have all the control values irrespective of its disable status.

Comment: That's very strange indeed : in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ganeshtechie-form-control-example-qd4jug?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html), the form is neither valid, nor invalid. I suggest you check the invalid state instead, which depends on the errors.

Comment: awesome. this is exactly what i need. thank you very much

Comment: If you have the courage to, open an issue with the latter stackblitz to show the issue !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176860/discussion-between-ganesh-rajan-and-trichetriche).

Comment: sorry! its a mistake.